# Applying classes to a parent element with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to apply a class to the `<li>` tag that encloses an anchor tag when a user clicks on the link. Like this:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Just an Example</a></li>
</ul>
```

So when the user clicks on `<a href="#">Just an Example</a>`, I need to apply a class to the `<li>` enclosing it. How would I target this? I am using jquery.

Comment: The documentation is quite good: http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('theClass');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('a[href=#]').click(function(){
   $(this).closest('li').addClass('your_class_name');
});
```

If its guaranteed that the parent element of such an anchor is a `LI` you might also use

```
$(this).parent().addClass('your_class_name');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a").click(function() {
   $(this).parent().whateveryouwant();
}
```